# Mapbox Studio cuts off bottom corner of shapefile polygon

Tags: mapbox, qgis

I am uploading a shapefile to Mapbox Studio. Here is a screenshot of the shapefile polygon in QGis

[image: This is the polygon in QGis]

Now, when I zip the files and upload them as a new tileset, the bottom corner is missing at the edge of a Tile boundary. See the screenshot below.

[image: See the screenshot below to see the problem.]

How can I prevent this problem when I upload to Mapbox Studio. I have had this problem with every shapefile that I upload.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Mapbox Studio.